# How to read content from nodeRef in alfresco using Java

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to read content from a file in nodeREF (ps: the treatment is in a behavior). I tried to get a plainText with:

```
ContentReader reader = contentService.getReader(nodeRef,
            ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
```

it works only with .txt files not with pdf and docs. The problem that alfresco could not read the file after that so is there any other solution?

Comment: You should read from the readers InputStream (reader.getContentInputStream()). What exactly is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: Acctually i'm trying tu put the text in a .txt file and i tryed to work with the contentInputStream but it's the same thing  (as a log or something like that) but i get something unreadble and i get numbers when it's word and excel documents, as i said when i try to open the file with alfresco Share it says that The preview can't be loaded from the server.

Comment: not sure if I got your right, the content stream of a .doc document is not text. Seems to me like you'want to get a text rendition and not the original content...